# Invoke same action method with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a webpage where the user has to enter some values in a textbox. Based on the value entered I have to populate another field in the same page with values from a db call.

I have a button "Search" which when clicked will take the values from the textbox and populate another field with values from a db call.

I have single method Create with a parameter SOWNO.The value of the parameter SOWNO should come from the textbox (I am using Html.Textbox("SOWNO") in the view.

Point to be considered, the same form will be used to submit completed values to the DB using the HTTP[Post] version of the Create Action method.

Please see the code below

```
public ActionResult Create(string SOWNO)
{

        ONBOARDING_DATA od = new ONBOARDING_DATA();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SOWNO))
        {
            List<SelectListItem> kins = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var xx = repository.GetAllKinIds(SOWNO);

            foreach(string kinid in xx)
            {
                kins.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = kinid, Value = kinid });
            }

            ViewBag.KinIdList = kins;
        }

        return View(od);
    }
```

Here is the code for the view

```
@model ScopeSow.Models.ONBOARDING_DATA
@{
ViewBag.Title = "New Onboarding Request";
}

<section id="contact">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Onboarding")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Onboarding Request</legend>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Sow No:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBox("SOWNO")
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input Type="button" value="Search" class="selectbutton"   onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Onboarding")'" />
                </td>
                <td>Kin Id:</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.KIN_ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.KinIdList, "Value","Text"), new {@class="form-control"})

                     </div>
                </td>
```

I want to use the value in the Html.Textbox("SOWNO") as the parameter to the Create Action method.

So the Route should be something like this /Onboarding/Create/?SOWNO=some value
where Onboarding is the controller and Create is the action method.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks
Parameswaran

Comment: Are you wanting to do this without javascript?

Comment: If possible without Javascript, but anyways i need a solution, any solution

Comment: Why does it need to be the same action method? Without javascript, you will need multiple methods and/or views (a 3 step wizard). With javascript/AJAX (better performance and less code) you will need a separate method to return JSON or a PartialView

Comment: Agree, so how to do this in Javascript?  Any example will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of textbox,

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor("SOWNO")
</div>
```